# Is GCS only accessible via URLFetch from AppEngine? And does it considers all UrlFetch quotas or only calls/request & not incoming/outgoing bandwidth?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

***Google Cloud Storage is accessed by the App Engine UrlFetch feature***

Is this always the case? No matter what I use to connect to Google Cloud Storage from AppEngine - All client libraries, any language, will always use UrlFetch feature to access Google Cloud Storage

Also
This is an excerpt from App engine - cloud storage client document

*There are **no bandwidth charges** associated with making **Google Cloud Storage client library calls to Cloud Storage**. However, there are operations charges; because the **calls count against your URL fetch quota**, as the library uses the URL Fetch service to interact with Cloud Storage. And There are operations and storage charges*

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#pricing_quotas_and_limits

Does this means that out of 3 quotas of URL Fetch (call/request count, outgoing bandwidth and incoming bandwidth) only call/request count is added against the url fetch quota. Aren't Url Fetch Incoming and Outgoing bandwidth quota considered and added too?

Sorry, my GCP free billing account got expired recently and I'm planning to renew it in next month. So till then not able to try out and verify the second part of the question.

Thanks.

Kiran.

Comment: You probably knew this, but a reminder to others: GCS can absolutely be used from outside of App Engine, and outside of App Engine there are no UrlFetch issues.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all 3 quotas of URL fetch count in this case.

Instead of finding a way around these limitations, you could maybe think about redesigning your application.

As [Nick](http://google-app-engine.75637.x6.nabble.com/cloudstorage-library-and-URLFetch-quotas-workaround-td608.html) from Cloud Platform Support puts it:

> look into the use of [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview?hl=en) to store the temporary results of your
>   process, since this will have better rate-limiting quotas than cloud
>   storage, which **isn't really meant for rapid writes** such as this. You
>   could also look into [BigTable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/), or any number of distributed databases
>   such as memcached to resolve your issue of temporary file storage.

Comment: Thanks Serge:)
So just to make sure tht I understand conceptually correct, For Cloud Storage clientlibrary request to GCS from appengine, all 3 quotas r incremented. Its just that incomng & bandwidth charges r not applied tht will be otherwise for URLfetch in someother case. Right?

My confusion is because of this statement:
`However, there are **operations charges** because the **calls count against your URL fetch quota** as the **library uses the URL Fetch service to interact with Cloud Storage** `

So by calls count against url fetch quota, it's all 3 and not just the api call quota.